# jQuery/CSS hover over a button only when it has a certain background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a button and a checkmark ("agree") next to it. The checkmark is hidden. The button can have 3 different states (white.png, red.png, green.png) depending on real-time validation of the input in the form. **UPD:** It's not a normal-hover-clicked button. It is a submit button also  indicating whether the form is empty OR can't be sent OR can be sent. **Only when the background image of the button is "green.png"**, that checkmark should become visible on button hover. And this is my non-working code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#checkmark").css("background-image", "url(checkmark.png)").hide();
        if ($("#button_send").css("background-image", "url(green.png)")){
        $("#button_send").hover(
            function() {
                $("#checkmark").show();
            },
            function() {
                $("#checkmark").hide();
            }
        );
        };
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: please share html code...

Comment: Can be handled better by CSS

Comment: To expand on @Satpal on-point comment: when you are setting the background to be whichever color it should be, you should also add a corresponding class - then, with pure CSS, you can make any element with that class visible on hover....

Comment: thank you for your swift answers! The button has 3 different states (background images) depending on real-time validation of the input in the form, it's not a "normal-hover-clicked" button, I must clarify. It would be better if done with jQuery...

Comment: if you were to add/remove classes on your hover button with javascript you should be able to use css for the button animation.

Comment: adding classes would probably be a better idea, you're right. I can't make background-image work neither with my code nor with suggested codes. Thank you everyone for every piece of advice and help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the value on the if using the `includes(string)` method.

As you can see in the snippet. I declared the `background` as url(green.png), but the value is url("https://stacksnippets.net/green.png"). `includes` will help you validate without specific url

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      //$("#checkmark").css("background-image", "url(checkmark.png)").hide();
console.log($("#button_send").css("background-image"))

if ($("#button_send").css("background-image").includes('green.png')) {
      $("#button_send").hover(
        function() {
          console.log('hover Good')
          //$("#checkmark").show();
        },
        function() {
          //$("#checkmark").hide();
        }
      );
    };
})
```

```css
#button_send {
  background-image: url(green.png);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button_send">Send</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks very good, but If I add background-image: url(green.png); to #button_send in CSS, green.png sits under any other button state/image and always triggers checkmark on hover visibility, If I don't put it there, checkmark doesn't want to show up at all... :) I'll try to find out what may interfere with this button and get back.

Comment: If you provide more code. I can help you so you can upvote and we can conclude the answer

Comment: Ok;) seems like something is interfering with something. I'll add more information after trying another thing using your code.

Comment: something is in conflict with something in my code - the button behaves not as expected. I'm trying to find out what exactly is the problem. :|

Comment: Thank you! It helped to find and tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use selector

```
$("#button_send").hover(
        function() {
        if ($('#button_send[style^="background-image:"][style$="green.png)"]').length > 0) {
            $("#checkmark").show();
        }
        },
        function() {
            if ($('#button_send[style^="background-image:"][style$="green.png)"]').length > 0) {
                $("#checkmark").hide();
            }
        }
    );
```